# Can we debug .NET desktop apps in Docker container

Tags: docker, windows-10

*(The more I dig this, the more confusing it gets. I have found Windows images available to download, but none of them appears to be the standard desktop OS)*

Is there a way to debug my .NET Framework or .NET Core/5/6 desktop application (WinForms, WPF, VSTO) in a Docker container running Windows 10? I'm just trying to setup a playground environment that I could put together quickly and test my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my own notes and any future beginner, here is my current finding:

Docker is not a full-fledged virtual machine like what we get with VirtualBox, VMWare etc. It's more like **a process in an isolated environment**, called a **Container**. For example you could create a container that runs an instance of MySQL, or a container that runs an instance of NodeJS. Of course there are images containing Operating System too, such as Ubuntu, Alpine or even Windows, but those images do not contain the full desktop environment; they are just the base OS services.

So answering the question, no, this is not (currently?) possible at least for Windows. People have had success running Ubuntu desktop inside a Docker container, but that is an advanced topic and only works in Linux-based containers. I haven't seen anything like that for Windows.